# FullCalendar v6.1 is producing 50 `ARIA attribute unsupported or prohibited` errors on GridCalendar view using SiteImprove browser extension

Tags: html, fullcalendar, wai-aria, fullcalendar-6

## The Errors

I am working on a website that is required by law to maintain a certain level of accessibility. We use SiteImprove (a free browser extension) to check for issues. I'm getting 50 errors on the `GridCalendar` view.

> **ARIA attribute unsupported or prohibited** - An ARIA attribute has been specified that is either not supported or is prohibited, on this type of element.

## The HTML

49 of these errors are reported as `aria-label on a` and they all look similar to this...

```
<a aria-label="October 1, 2023" id="fc-dom-2" class="fc-daygrid-day-number">1</a>
```

1 of these errors is reported as `aria-labelledby on div` and html looks like this...

```
<div aria-labelledby="fc-dom-1" class="fc-view-harness fc-view-harness-active" style="height: 687.407px;">
    <div class="fc-dayGridMonth-view fc-view fc-daygrid">
        <table role="grid" class="fc-scrollgrid  fc-scrollgrid-liquid">
            ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Description

**For the `aria-label on a` issue** - I noticed that the `<a>` tags don't have an `href` attribute, which isn't really good practice. So when I added it manually and pointed it something, the error went away. But when I tried just changing the tag to a `<span>` the error still remained. I checked the FullCalendar GitHub issues and found a Pull Request that might have to do with this at https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/pull/6266.

**For the `aria-labelledby on div` issue** - I'm not actually sure what to do for this one either frankly. I tried removing the `aria-labelledby` attribute and of course the error went away but that's probably not the right solution. What do I do for this one?

## Summary

1. In short I'm not really sure how to solve these ADA issues so I can make any appropriate suggestions, or fix them locally for myself.
2. I would submit a bug report, if these are truly bugs, but they mentioned that "[A reduced test case is required](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug-report.yml)" and it seems a little daunting to submit.

Answer (score 0):

An `aria-label` on an anchor tag, <a>, is perfectly valid.  However, an anchor tag without an `href` will **not** be keyboard focusable.  It's considered a "[placeholder link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:represents-2)".  I think siteimprove might be confused on the error it's trying to report. A placeholder link is not an error in and of itself but it might be a mistake and siteimprove should give you a warning or a "you should check this" message.  It sounds like you proved that already by adding an `href` and the siteimprove message went away.

`aria-labelledby` and `aria-label` are valid on a <div> **if** that <div> also has a [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions).  Without a role, the ARIA attribute will most likely be ignored.  See the third *last* bullet point of "[2.10 Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)"

> Don't use aria-label or aria-labelledby on a span or div unless its given a role.

It's not technically an error if you use an `aria-labelledby` on a `<div>` without a role but the label will most likely not be read. I think siteimprove might be trying to warn you about that.